# Current month and prevoius month logic in cognos prompt page

Tags: sql, db2, reporting, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I want to designed a report in a cognos which showcase data for current month or prevoius month choice on prompt page, need to get logic for this.
Please advice if any one has solution for this...

Comment: Hi @VIRAL_ZONE, please provide some sample data.

Comment: Hi Vishnu, i have data for some Dealers (say Dealer code,name,contact etc)

Comment: Hi Vishnu, i have data for some Dealers (say Dealer code as identifier,name,contact etc), date column as Reporting Month (data type as date & format is 'YYYYMM') ...Report Prompt should filter on Dealer Code, and Current Month or prevoius month  logic... Let me know if you want more clarrification...

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to understand the question. Please add the table structure to the question.

Comment: Not very sure what you are asking as you have not given much details, but if its just about the month fetch logic then you can use MONTH(COL_NAME) = MONTH(CURRENT DATE) and MONTH(COL_NAME) = MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) for previous month

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions

Scenario 1) Put the current month and prior month values in a conditional block

Or if you don't want to do that,

Scenario 2) 
Create two lists
One each way you want to present the data

- Current Month
- Prior Month

Then use rendering on the prompt to show the list the user selected